# How to show multiple row in single row using gridview

Tags: yii, yii-components, cgridview

i want to show grid view like magento
http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalog/category/view/s/cellphones/id/8/

here we can see that multiple items are shown in same row...
on the above link we can see that 3 item(rows) are shown per row..

currently i'm using this code and using this single row are shown per row

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'enablePagination'=>false,
    'columns'=>array(
        'brand',
        array(
          'name'=>'model',
            'header'=>'Model',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'$data->model.($data->marketing_name?" (".$data->marketing_name.") ":"")'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=> 'platform',
            'header'=>'Platform',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'$data->platform->platform." ".$data->platform->platform_version'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'add',
            'header'=>'Action',
            'type'=>'html',
            'value'=>  'CHtml::link("Add To My device", Yii::app()->createUrl("/site/add_device/id/".$data->id))',
        )
    ),
));
?>
```

Comment: Use [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGridView` always displays each item in a separate row. For more flexibility (e.g. displaying three items side by side) you have to switch to using [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) instead, but this means you have to do more things yourself.

`CListView` has an [`itemView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#itemView-detail) attribute that you have to set and uses the specified view to render each item in the list. Together with the [`template`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#template-detail) and [`itemsTagName`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#itemsTagName-detail) attributes this lets you fully customize the HTML produced by your list.

To display three items per row you can use any general-purpose CSS technique such as giving each item `display: inline-block` and a fixed width of 1/3 of the container width; this will depend on how you want to achieve your layout.